# Python: retailitem class

Tags: python, class

So I am writing a class that works but it doesn't exactly give me what I want. This is my code.

```
class RetailItem(): 
    def __init__(self,ItemDesc,unit_Inv,Price):
        self.ItemDesc=ItemDesc 
        self.unit_Inv=unit_Inv 
        self.Price=Price  
    def get_ItemDesc(self): 
        return self.ItemDesc 
    def get_unit_Inv(self): 
        return self.unit_Inv
    def get_Price(self): 
        return self.Price 

def main(): 

    ItemDesc1=RetailItem('Jacket', '12', '59.95')

    unit_Inv1=ItemDesc1.get_unit_Inv() 
    Price1=ItemDesc1.get_Price() 

    ItemDesc2=RetailItem('Designer Jeans', '40', '34.95') 
    unit_Inv2=ItemDesc2.get_unit_Inv() 
    Price2=ItemDesc2.get_Price() 


    ItemDesc3=RetailItem('Shirt', '20', '24.95') 
    unit_Inv3=ItemDesc3.get_unit_Inv() 
    Price3=ItemDesc3.get_Price() 


    print('Description  Units In Inventory  Price') 
    print('_________________________________')
    print(ItemDesc1,unit_Inv1, Price1, sep=' ') 
    print(ItemDesc2,unit_Inv2,Price2,sep=' ') 
    print(ItemDesc3,unit_Inv3,Price3,sep=' ') 

main()
```

The output it gives me is

```
    Description  Units In Inventory  Price
_________________________________
<__main__.RetailItem object at 0x01AF6C10> 12 59.95
<__main__.RetailItem object at 0x03BB8250> 40 34.95
<__main__.RetailItem object at 0x04062510> 20 24.95
```

my desired outcome should be something like:

```
 Description   Units In Inventory Price
__________________________________________
Jacket          12                   59.95
Designer Jeans  40                   34.95
Shirt           20                   24.95
```

so my question is where did I go wrong? I thought maybe it needs another line of code for the actual name itself. However, when I did that it gave me a typerror. Some pointers and advice would be nice.

Comment: You need to implement `__str__` method. Also in Python, property names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: It gives me a type error..

Comment: or print `ItemDesc1.ItemDesc` as first argument of `print` (but i would really suggest you implement `__str__` as a method of your class).

Comment: I did that before it only gave me the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a **str** method to your class, so the description is returned as a string instead of the python object.

```
class RetailItem():
    def __init__(self,ItemDesc,unit_Inv,Price):
        self.ItemDesc=ItemDesc
        self.unit_Inv=unit_Inv
        self.Price=Price
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ItemDesc
    def get_ItemDesc(self):
        return self.ItemDesc
    def get_unit_Inv(self):
        return self.unit_Inv
    def get_Price(self):
        return self.Price

def main():

    ItemDesc1=RetailItem('Jacket', '12', '59.95')
    ItemDesc2=RetailItem('Designer Jeans', '40', '34.95')
    ItemDesc3=RetailItem('Shirt', '20', '24.95')

    print('Description  Units In Inventory  Price')
    print('_________________________________')
    print(ItemDesc1, ItemDesc1.get_unit_Inv(), ItemDesc1.get_Price(), sep=' ')
    print(ItemDesc2, ItemDesc2.get_unit_Inv(), ItemDesc2.get_Price(), sep=' ')
    print(ItemDesc3, ItemDesc3.get_unit_Inv(), ItemDesc3.get_Price(), sep=' ')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, I solved it myself apparently I did need to add another line for the item description.

basically this is what I needed.

```
ItemDesc03=ItemDesc3.get_ItemDesc()
```